# How authenticate users credentials on page load without login

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, authentication

I am building a website through Visual Studio 2013 and i am looking to obtain the person's user name when the page loads and then displays it.

I have tried some code from another website but this just brings up the windows authentication asking the user to log in but i want to avoid this. So all i want is for a function to grab the username before the page loads and then automatically displays on screen.

The code i used..

```
Public Shared Function GetUserName() As String

    If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is 
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then

        Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim username As String = parts(1)
        Return username

    Else
        Return LCase(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString())

    End If

End Function
```

Could you also help me on how i call the function on my aspx.vb page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    GetUserName()

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure IIS to enable integrated security and disable anonymous logon (that is one reason why you are being prompted for the usernam)

Once you have done that, some code like this should give you the username:

```
If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
   Return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
Else
    Return "Unknown"
End If
```

Comment: thank you, do you know how i would call this function in my aspx.vb  page?

Comment: Just as you have in your question.